# How do you add a query for data grouped by a regex in influxdb to grafana?

Tags: influxdb, grafana

So my main goal is to build a graph that charts how much data I've went through in a month in grafana (I'm on a comcast line).

Month is not a time period however that influxdb's `GROUP BY time()` function supports. [The documentation I looked at.](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.1/query_language/data_exploration/#group-by-time-intervals) From here it looks like the longest time period is a week, likely because it doesn't change like a month does.

However I noticed that all my time stamps use the same format (it would be weird if they didn't I guess). I know that influxdb supports regex FROM and WHERE statements, but does it support GROUP BY? If it did, I could use something like `"/-([^-]+)-/"` to query timestamps like `2016-12-18T08:25:50Z` and group by that? Or does influxdb support nested queries?

edit: looks like I was looking at .9. I edited to 1.1 but didn't edit anything about my question.

> `GROUP BY time()` queries group query results by a user-specified time interval

I'm not really sure how that would work for a month considering that my length of time changes?

Answer (score 0):

No version of InfluxDB supports `GROUP BY <regular expression>`, but as on [`1.2` subqueries will be supported](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/pull/7646).

Comment: Thank you. I ended up solving this issue by writing a small python script with the influxdb client

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear that you got something working.

Comment: What I wanted was just too complex for a single query